# C++ Refactoring - Move method to implementation file

Tags: c++, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I have lots of header files with long method implementation inside.

Is there An automatic way of doing that?

One-by-one can take a lot of time...

Thanks.

Comment: You can easily create a script in some other language (or even use C++ if you want to do that). I am unaware of anything that does that automatically for you though.

Comment: @Peter R.: I don't think that creating a script that parses C++ good enough to do this job is done easily!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, there's an add-in called [**Visual Assist**](http://www.wholetomato.com/) that can help you to do this. I'm using it at work and it is really helpful.

Unfortunately this add-in is not free but you can install the trial to do your stuff and test it.

Comment: I know about Visual Assist. It does require me to review all the header files and click a lot... You can't even set a hotkey...

Comment: @Tsury: Most Visual Assist commands can be bound to any keybinding you want via Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard.  Show commands containing: VAssistX.Refactor

Comment: Visual Studio can also do it without Visual Assist. The feature is marked as experimental though. You can use it by pressing `Ctrl + .` and then choosing `Move definition location`.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse CDT its combination is `Alt+Shift+T`

Comment: :s Im getting: Cannot work without declarator...

Answer (score 1):

KDevelop has such ability too:

Right click to the method -> Refactoring -> Move to cpp

Answer (score 0):

There's a free version of DevExpress [Refactor! for C++](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/RefactorCPP/) that has two automatic 'refactorings' that may suit your needs:

- Move Method to Source File
- Move Method to Header

[Refactorings Reference link](http://help.devexpress.com/#RefactorPro/CustomDocument2937)