# Is there a tool for automatic conversion of header into cpp and hpp files?

Tags: c++, ide

I have a (possibly bad) habit of coding everything into a monolithic header file when trying out ideas, placing all implementation code with the class definitions. As the code expands, it becomes difficult to navigate the file. Therefore, I refactor the code into separate files and split the implementation details (cpp files) from the interface (hpp files).

The laborious copy / pasting involved seems like a job for a machine. Are there any simple tools available for this task?

Comment: "implementation details (hpp files) from the interface (cpp files)." Other way around, right?

Comment: An inch of prevention's worth a pound of cure which results in some amount of inch-pounds per file. I'd agree with "possibly bad".

Comment: @Johnsyweb In a parallel universe, source files are used to declare interfaces used in an interface-implementing interface file ;). More seriously,  edited his question.

Comment: Easiest way would be to drop your <strike>probably</strike> definitely bad habit.

Comment: His habit is not always bad. Consider the case where he test his code with ideone or codepad, for example on his phone or on a non-dev machine... (But I agree it is not that good in general).

Comment: Sounds more like he's using testing as a substitute for designing, but I've been wrong in the past.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [Lazy C++](http://www.lazycplusplus.com/), as stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852502/tool-to-parse-c-source-and-move-in-header-inline-methods-to-the-cpp-source-fi).

You can also use a standard IDE, and move each function from header to source (for Visual Studio you can use Visual Assist, I think Eclipse can do it straight), generally it's like right click > refactor > move to source or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is quite common. My approach is to only cut and paste once: make a copy of the original file, then chop stuff from the header and chop other stuff from the source file.